# Error while starting Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

While starting the Mongodb I got this error is socket connection:

```
7 12:03:31.230 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Apr  7 12:03:31.230 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Apr  7 12:03:31.252 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:28017
Tue Apr  7 12:03:31.253 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem today, `sudo service mongod restart` or `sudo service mongod stop` does not really stop `mongod` process. I follow below steps solved the problem:

1. Find `mongod` process id (414)

   ```
   $ sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 27017
   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      414/mongod
   ```
2. Kill `mongod`

   ```
   sudo kill -9 414
   ```
3. Start `mongod`

   ```
   sudo service mongod start
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This likely means that another instance of mongodb is already running. You can use the following command to restart it:

> sudo service mongod restart